# Resultado automatico con PHP y Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy haciendo un ingreso de datos en lo cual tengo dos puntos que no se como hacerlos en ajax o jquery.

```
<?php
$valor = 320; //valor en pesos
?>

Ingreso <input type="date" name="ingreso" autocomplete="off"><br>
Retiro <input type="date" name="retiro" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="text" name="totaldias" placeholder="Total de dias" disabled="disabled"><br>
$ <input type="text" name="valor" placeholder="Valor" disabled="disabled"><br>
```

Los que quiero hacer es que cuando el input ingrese las fechas, me coloque automaticamente la cantidad de dias y una vez que tenga la cantidad de dias me los multiplique por el valor.

Espero me ayuden. Gracias

Comment: ¿La cantidad de días es el rango de días entre el ingreso y el retiro? Por ejemplo si el ingreso es: 17-07-2018 y el retiro: 19-07-2018, ¿La cantidad de días sería 2? ¿Eso es lo que buscas?

Comment: Eso lo se hacer, y tambien puedo hacer que esa cantodad se multiplique por el valor del alquiler, lo que trato de hacer es que lo resultado se muestren al instante antes de guardarlos

Comment: Perfecto ¿Y esos valores (las multiplicaciones de días etc, ) desde donde los haces, desde jqery? Podrías intentar poner tu código completo para poder ayudarte de manera optima. Te recomiendo editar tu preguntar y poner tu código completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esto te puede ayudar. Le agregue algunas cosas al html para tomar el valor de los input. Tomas los valores de las fechas, pero solo después de llenar el input de retiro el hace el calculo, a través de un evento onChange

```
<?php
$valor = 320; //valor en pesos
$tasa_cambio_dolares = 0.036;//1 peso argentino = 0.036
?>

Ingreso <input type="date" id="ingreso" name="ingreso" autocomplete="off"><br>
Retiro <input type="date" id="retiro" name="retiro" autocomplete="off" onChange="data(<?php echo $valor?>, <?php echo $tasa_cambio_dolares?>)"><br>
<input type="text" name="totaldias" id="totaldias" placeholder="Total de dias" disabled="disabled"><br>
$ <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="Valor" disabled="disabled"><br>
$ <input type="text" name="dolares" id="dolares" placeholder="Valor Dolares" disabled="disabled"><br>


<script>
    function data(valor, tasa_cambio){
        let ingreso = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
        let retiro = document.getElementById("retiro").value;

        let fechaInicio = new Date(ingreso).getTime();
        let fechaFin    = new Date(retiro).getTime();

        let diff = fechaFin - fechaInicio;//Diferencia en milisegundos
        let dias = diff/(1000*60*60*24);//Diferencia en dias

        document.getElementById("totaldias").value = dias;
        document.getElementById("valor").value = dias*valor;
        document.getElementById("dolares").value = dias*valor*tasa_cambio;

    }

</script>
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose, disculpa no haberte contestado ayer. Voy a jugar un poco con el  codigo, por me olvide de tambien tiene agregar el tipo de cambio, tanto en dolares como en pesos argentinos. Pero gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Estoy tratando de agregar el tipo de cambio: `let peso = document.getElementById("pesos").value;
 let dolares = document.getElementById("dolares").value;` - `document.getElementById("pesos").value = pesos;
 document.getElementById("dolares").value = dolares;` y como resultado modique el valor: `document.getElementById("valor").value = dias*valor*dolares;` teniendo en cuenta que agregue un input radio pero con pesos y dolares. El problema es que no me da ningun resultado. Porque?

Comment: Dolares es una variable php o un input HTML?

Comment: perdon, si, es una variable en php y lo agregue asi en el html: `Pesos <input type="radio" id="pesos" name="pesos" value="pesos" onChange="data(<?php echo $peso?>)">

Dolares <input type="radio" id="dolares" name="dolares" value="dolares" onChange="data(<?php echo $dolar?>)"><br>` Puse el `id=""` en el input, pero la verdad no se porque, en un momento no me daba ningun resultado, despues de poner el id me trajo la cantidad de dias pero no el valor. - pido disculpas por no saber

Comment: El problema es que la función javascript requiere ahora dos variables y tu solo le pasas una. No es necesario incluir ese evento en input dolares, porque la acción se ejecuta es con la selección de fechas. Revisa la edición que hice a mi respuesta original

Comment: Estoy tratando de entender, pero esta no son dos variables? `let peso = document.getElementById("pesos").value;
 let dolares = document.getElementById("dolares").value;`

Comment: El unput va a mostrar un resultado total, osea, como tu lo tienes planteado, es una salida, no una entrada. La entrada debe ser a través de los argumentos de la funcion, como sucede con la variable $valor

Comment: Gracias Jose, estoy tratando de entender lo que me dices, asi que voy a ver como me va y te cuento. Muchas gracias nuevamente!